# datos duplicados Distinct - oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo la siguiente consulta que devuelve datos duplicados con Distinct, como se muestra en la imagen, como podría genera solo un dato sin repetirse .

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDEXPEDIENTE, INFORME, OFICIO FROM temp_PruebaReporte
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *”generar solo un dato”* ¿Cuál?

Comment: ¿Tienes múltiples registros con mismo IDEXPEDIENTE?

Comment: que retorne un solo dato algo asi:                                                                            IDEXPEDIENTE : 181  INFORME : DOCUMENTO 21  OFICIO:documento 156